# GetAwaiter().GetResult() vs GetAwaiter()?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Most devs are using `GetAwaiter().GetResult()`, and I can barely dig up examples using it with without the `GetResult()` part, however it is illogical to use `GetResult()` when we don't need the result.

Is there a reason why not just use `GetAwaiter()` when applicable? Or is my perception of what the common usage is wrong?

Comment: GetResult waits for the completion of the task ie [`Ends the wait for the completion of the asynchronous task.`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.taskawaiter.getresult?view=netframework-4.8#System_Runtime_CompilerServices_TaskAwaiter_GetResult).. `GetAwaiter()` does as the name implies. [`Gets an awaiter used to await a Task.`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.getawaiter?view=netframework-4.8) quotes taken directly from docs.

Comment: So my interpretation is not that you need a result but more that you want to wait for the awaiter to complete.

Answer (score 3):

`GetAwaiter()` not waits for task, just returns `TaskAwaiter` object, which can be used to wait for task by calling `GetResult()`. So calling `GetAwaiter()` only is meaningless. As [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.taskawaiter?view=netframework-4.8) states this class is only intended of compiler use and users should not use it. You should use `Task.Wait()`, when you want to wait for task, but not need result. But sometimes users still use Task.GetAwaiter().GetResult(), Instead of Task.Wait() in try-catch block because Task.GetAwaiter().GetResult() not wraps `Exception` thrown while executing task in `AggregateException` and also shows more detailed stack trace, that makes exception handling easier.